# Using yii2 renderJs function to getElementById

Tags: javascript, yii, yii2

I have two date variables `$startDate` and `$endDate` gotten from two date fields

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="col-md-11 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback">
      <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="single_cal3"
        placeholder="First Name" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status3">
      <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span id="inputSuccess2Status3" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="col-md-11 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback">
      <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" id="single_cal4"
        placeholder="First Name" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status4">
      <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span id="inputSuccess2Status4" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which I am trying to pass across in a URL using yii registerJs function and JavaScript's `getElementById` function

```php
<?php

echo Html::a(
    ' Arrival List Report',
    [
        'arrival-list-report',
        'startDate' => $this->registerJs("document.getElementById(\'single_cal3\');", View::POS_READY),
        'endDate' => $this->registerJs("document.getElementById(\'single_cal4\');", View::POS_READY)
    ]
)
```

But every time I click the link, it doesn't get any of the variables. I am new to yii framework, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are accessit server side to a  value that is know client side .. $this->registerJs("document.getElementById(\'single_cal4\');  this is evaluated  client side bur the  anchor is build server side  ..  so you should change the way you get this values

Comment: okay, i will try getting them in a separate function first before passing to the anchor. thanks